# How to fix a System.FormatException on a dateTimePicker while trying to translate with ini file

Tags: translation, datetimepicker, tabcontrol, ini

i'm new to encoding and i'm trying to translate runtime my controls inside several tabs using a ini file. My current culture is French.

According to a comboBox, users can select a language then labels and controls must be translated.

However a System.FormatException error occured when it tries to translate the control text of a dateTimePicker.

Here is the content of control when it crashes : {System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 01/05/2019 23:34:21} I can use any help !

```
    {
        // Translating each control inside each tab
        foreach (Control tab in tabControl1.Controls)
        {
            // Translating the tab name
            tab.Text = Languages.GetTranslation(comboBoxLanguages.SelectedItem.ToString(), tab.Name);

            // Translating each control (labels, buttons, grid columns...)
            // inside each tab
            foreach (Control control in tab.Controls)
            {

                // Translating the control text
                control.Text = Languages.GetTranslation(comboBoxLanguages.SelectedItem.ToString(), control.Name);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please could you provide a [mcve]? It's likely that you can just create a DateTimePicker and hard-code the value you're setting the Text property to. At the moment we don't know what that value is, or your current culture.

Comment: Sorry to ask i'm not yet use to stackoverflow's rules, is it good now? @JonSkeet

Comment: Well it's still not a [mcve]... it's not something we can just copy, paste, compile and run. In particular, we still don't know the value you're trying to *set* for `Text`, and we don't know the culture involved.

Comment: Here's a genuine [mcve] which throws the same exception: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/a62a9cfe74c41f344440e92b9980483a So, what's the equivalent of that, but for your problem? (And what culture are you using? And are you setting any other properties in the DateTimePicker?)